# In both case either the app is closed or foreground we need to get notification

Tags: android

Is it possible to getting notification only using data payload without use of Notification payload when app is background and foreground.

Comment: It's a good (recommended) practice to post [mcve] while asking questions in StackOverflow. So, the fellow StackOverflow users can look into your code and suggest the fix/solution.

Comment: @Shashanth thanks  for guidance. but this question is only for resolve the confusion on my mind because many answer related to notification  but does not clear regarding to actual working and use of  data payload and message payload

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```